# Showing that some Function on the Unit Disc is injective

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ be a holomophic function in the unit disc. Show that if $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n\vert a_n \vert <\vert a_1\vert$$ and $a_1\not = 0$, then $f$ is injective.

I am able to show that $f'$ never vanishes by showing that $\vert f'-a_1\vert <\vert a_1\vert$, but that doesn't imply that $f$ is injective. For example, $e^z$ is not inejective but its derivative never vanishes. What is required to prove that $f$ is injective? How do you show $f$ is injective on any set?

Comment: If $f$ is holomorphic and $f'$ takes values in a half plane which does not contain $0$ then $f$ is injective. If you can show this, your problem is solved since $|f'-a_1| < |a_1|$.

Comment: is that necessarily true that $f'$ lies in a half-plane?

Comment: $f$ must be defined in a convex domain for this to be true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f$ is analytic in $\mathbb{D}$, its derivative can be found by differentiating the series expansion of $f$ termwise:
$$
f'(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nz^{n-1}=a_1+2a_2z+3a_3z^2+\dots
$$
Thus for $z\in\mathbb{D}$, 
$$|f'(z)-a_1|=\left|\sum_{n=2}^\infty na_nz^{n-1}\right|\leq \sum_{n=2}^\infty n|a_n||z|^{n-1} <\sum_{n=2}^\infty n|a_n|<|a_1|.$$
From here, we can establish the injectivity of $f$ by taking $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{D}$ and noting that
\begin{align}
|f(z_2)-f(z_1)|&=\left|\int_{z_1}^{z_2}f'(z)dz\right|\\&=\left|a_1(z_2-z_1)+\int_{z_1}^{z_2}(f'(z)-a_1)dz\right| \\
&\geq |a_1||z_2-z_1|-|z_2-z_1|\sup\{\left|f'\left(z_1+t(z_2-z_1)\right)-a_1\right|:t\in[0,1]\} \\
&>|a_1||z_2-z_1|-|z_2-z_1||a_1|\\&=0.
\end{align}