# Injective holomorphic function defined on the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: Assume that the power series
$$f(z) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j z^j$$
defines a holomorphic function for $|z| < 1$ and assume that
$$|a_1| > \sum_{j=2}^\infty j |a_j|.$$
Show that the the function $f(z)$ is one-to-one in the open unit disk.

My attempt: I have tried to prove it via contradiction, that is if there exists $z_1\neq z_2 \in D_1(0)$ so that $f(z_2) - f(z_1) =0$ then the integral
$$\int_0^1 f'(t z_1 + (1-t) z_2)) \, dt =0,$$ however I am not sure how to use the hypothesis that $|a_1| > \sum_{j=2}^\infty j |a_j|$ to attain a contradiction. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Would this answer your question? [Showing that some Function on the Unit Disc is injective](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1322327)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing that some Function on the Unit Disc is injective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322327/showing-that-some-function-on-the-unit-disc-is-injective)